# Multiple Primary-Foreign Key connections between Tables Redundant?

Tags: foreign-key, primary-key, relational-theory, erd, rdbms

I have two tables, Reviews and Critic

[image]

I'm pretty new to RDBMS and I was wondering if the connection between Review.rID and Critic.Review is redundant?

My reasoning is that a single critic can have many reviews but each review is unique so I need a way to enforce the uniqueness of the Reviews. I did this via Review.rID which is unique. I also need to express that multiple critics can leave multiple reviews.

**However, I am already connecting the critic to the review by including a criticID within Review, so is it necessary for me to also connect a reviewID to a critic within Critic?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The review column in critic means a critic can only do one review, which would make that career very unfulfilling.  A primary key uniquely identifies a row, it might not necessarily enforce the uniqueness of content. In your case, the rID does not prevent the same review from being inserted multiple times.

A reviewer may have multiple reviews (including of the same movie). A review must come from one reviewer (unless you want to allow a review written by multiple critics).  Based on that model, you need the FK column cID in review and nothing in critic. Additionally, the cID column should have a not null constraint because a review must belong to a critic (unless you want reviews that don't belong to any critic).

The question now is how to prevent the same review from being INSERTed multiple times. The only reliable method I can think of is to hash the review content and store the result in a column with a unique constraint in the review table.

Comment: If I have the FK column cID in review and nothing in Critic, then what row in Critic does the FK in Review reference?

Comment: Also, the NOT NULL should go in the Review table correct? Since if I were to put it in the critic table, it would be unnecessary since Primary Keys cannot be redundant

Comment: CRITIC does not have a FK column to REVIEW. A row in CRITIC can have multiple rows in REVIEW.

Comment: The NOT NULL constraint does not imply uniqueness, it means that column must have a non-null value. You should have a NOT NULL constraint on the cID column in REVIEW and mID (you can't have a review on a NULL movie).

Answer (score 0):

A foreign key can only refer to a primary or unique key of another table.  The 1-M relation you drew between Critic.Review and Review.rID is impossible.